# How can use Entity Framework to configure 0 - 1 relation with non-normalized schema?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration, ef-fluent-api

I realize there are many zero to one questions out there but I am not having any luck understanding them relating to my scenario. When I say "non normalized schema," I mean there is no `Photo` table which would be very simple to configure for me. It seems every example I have looked at assumes tables are, "normalized (ie. they would have `Photo` and `Upload` tables)." Since, I don't have time to refactor this at the moment, here is my challenge.

Schema for database

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual ICollection<Upload> Uploads {get;set;}
    public Int32? PhotoId {get;set;}
    public Upload Photo {get;set;}
}

public class Upload
{
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}
```

There is a join table named `EmployeeUpload` so I can use the entities `employee.Uploads` or `upload.Employees`.

The many-to-many was simple to configure:

```
HasMany(t => t.Uploads)
    .WithMany(t => t.Employees)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("EmployeeUpload");
        m.MapLeftKey("EmployeeId");
        m.MapRightKey("UploadId");
    });
```

However, it seems that nothing I try will allow me to configure the latter which is the optional photo. I have tried just about every configuration I can think of but I always seem to get a configuration or database error. I even tried to do a `WithMany` from the `Upload` side but only some uploads have valid `Employee` it fails (I could be wrong here).

If possible I would like to leave the schema the way it is.

Comment: Well, a good start would be to show the database schema. What you show is a class model. And try to explain more exactly what you want to model. Yes, 0-1, but what is 0 (actually 0..1) and what is 1?

Comment: This is using code first and the nullable PhotoId explains the 0 does it not? It has been a while since I wrote this but the Upload